# spamming users with downvotes

Tags: discussion

Can I report someone for going to each question I asked and downvoting then, because every question on every site I have asked has gotten down voted with in 5 minutes of each other.I mean just saying that if i even get a single more downvote on a question i'll probably lose the privlege of asking questions on some stuff  need help with.

Comment: First of all, you should try an e-mail to the SE team ("contact us" link in the footer).

Comment: @Rudy Gruse - you may want to read the FAQ about asking questions on P.SE - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask, particularly point 1. I admire your zeal in approaching your ROV project, but your questions demonstrate that you have not done any research of your own into the subject of superconductivity, which leads to low quality questions and a propensity of other users to downvote.  You seem very interested in the subject, so I would suggest you do much reading and come back with specific questions about things you don't understand.

Comment: @Jen yah but it happened over 3 accounts which seemed more then just a coincedence- dont you agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy from the comment I left you: the Stack Exchange system automatically reverses runs of apparent "revenge downvoting". If the downvotes don't disappear within 36 hours, send an email to team@stackexchange.com identifying the questions that are still downvoted. There isn't anything that we (moderators) can do about it, though.

This is explained in more detail on the main meta site, for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/preventing-users-from-downvoting-good-answers-to-bad-questions/23010#23010).

Keep in mind that you can't lose the privilege of asking questions due to reputation. All users, even those with 1 reputation, can ask questions.

Comment: uhmm i lost mine for stack overflow they said "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account."the likely option they gave me was"Once you have posted too many bad quality questions, you will be banned from asking more, and see the error message. You can then still use the site, except for asking questions."

Comment: The repeated bad question thing doesn't depend on reputation as such,and though the formula is secret you can bet that it depends on the number of proportion of questions below 0 net score, closed and deleted.